Understanding async with SwiftUI Firebase .setData(from:) and .addData(from:)
I'm updating my FirebaseFirestore SwiftUI knowledge and had previously used a dictionary computed property to write/read data to Firestore with the async methods .setData([String:Any]) and .addDocument(data: [String:Any]), but it now looks like:
.addDocument(from:)
and
.setData(from:)
are document methods that can write anything that's codable, which is great. I did notice that these aren't async methods. With the updated code (see method below, then called from the Button code below that), and no async, do I need to worry about possibly not getting back the "success" value in time to respond to it after the .savePerson(person:) call in my Button action? I'm uncertain of the appropriate way to handle a possible problem with the save when there isn't an async in the saving methods - isn't there a concern that the save might take longer and the return directly below the statement will process ahead of a valid response on whether the set/add worked? Or is the statement immediately below the .setData(from:), .addDocument(from:) not going to execute until the save goes through or generates an error? Thanks!
func savePerson(person: Person) -> Bool {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    if let id = person.id { // person must already exist, so save
        do {
            try db.collection("people").document(id).setData(from: person)
            print(" Data updated successfully!")
            return true
        } catch {
            print(" ERROR: Could not update data in 'people' \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return false
        }
    } else { // no id? Then this must be a new person to add
        do {
            try db.collection("people").addDocument(from: person)
            print(" Data added successfully!")
            return true
        } catch {
            print(" ERROR: Could not create a new person in 'people' \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return false
        }
    }
}

Then call it in "Save" button like this:
Button("Save") {
    let success =  personVM.savePerson(person: person)
    if success {
        dismiss()
    } else {
        print(" Dang! Error saving person!")
    }
}

